# How to create a relationship class between a feature layer and a standalone table

Tags: arcobjects, c#, table, relationship-class

I need to create a join between a shapefile and a table that have been added to the map, the issue seems to be with the

```
            memRelFact.Open("Table-Layer", (IObjectClass)fromTable, "TableFieldName" 
            + featureClass, "FeatureClassFieldName", "FeatureClassName", "TableName" 
            + esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne);
```

I can't figure out how to fix the issue,  the error message is 'no overload method for 'Open' takes 6 arguments' here is the entire class code:

```
    public void JoinTables()
    {
        //Define the feature class
        IMxDocument mxDoc;
        IMap map;
        IFeatureLayer featureLayer;
        IFeatureClass featureClass;
        mxDoc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
        map = mxDoc.FocusMap;
        featureLayer = (IFeatureLayer)mxDoc.FocusMap.Layer[0];
        featureClass = featureLayer.FeatureClass;

        //Define the table to be joined
        IStandaloneTableCollection tabCollection;
        IStandaloneTable stTable;
        ITable fromTable;
        tabCollection = (IStandaloneTableCollection)map;
        stTable = tabCollection.StandaloneTable[0];//census
        fromTable = stTable.Table;

        //Join the table to the feature class
        IMemoryRelationshipClassFactory memRelFact;
        IRelationshipClass relClass;
        IDisplayRelationshipClass dispRC;
        // Create a memory relationship class
        // Cardinality is forward (origin to destination)
        // Options are: OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany
        memRelFact = new MemoryRelationshipClassFactory();
        relClass = memRelFact.Open("Table-Layer", (IObjectClass)fromTable, "TableFieldName" 
            + featureClass, "FeatureClassFieldName", "FeatureClassName", "TableName" 
            + esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne);
        // Perform a join
        dispRC = (IDisplayRelationshipClass)featureLayer;
        dispRC.DisplayRelationshipClass(relClass, esriJoinType.esriLeftOuterJoin);
     }
```

Comment: 'No overload method for Open takes 6 arguments' is the error message.  I edited my question, thanks for the advice, I'm new to this

Answer (score 1):

Check your arguments.
There's not enough in your call.

Is that supposed to be a comma between "TableFieldName" and featureclass, and "TableName" and the cardinality?

That will give you 8 arguments.

```
 memRelFact.Open("Table-Layer", (IObjectClass)fromTable, "TableFieldName" 
        , featureClass, "FeatureClassFieldName", "FeatureClassName", "TableName" 
        , esriRelCardinality.esriRelCardinalityOneToOne);
```